# GRE tunnel behind NAT with static IP

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, gre

In order to experiment with IPv6, I got from a broker some public IPv6 addresses. My ISP does not provide them, unfortunately. The broker provides 6in4 using a GRE tunnel.

My network is the following. I have the ISP modem and I have assigned to it a static IPv4 address. The modem is connected to the main router and the router interface has an internal private IPv4 address 192.168.1.110/24 given by the mode. The modem has in fact a DHCPv4.

The easiest thing would be to set the modem in AP mode or bridge mode so my router interface would have the static IP address from the ISP but this is not possible.

Then I'm wondering how would a GRE tunnel works behind a NAT?

I've tried to run configure the tunnel but unfortunately no results.

```
ip tunnel add tun0 mode gre remote <broker-ipv4> local <my-static-ipv4> dev eth0
ip -6 addr add <ipv6-client-api>/mask dev tun0
ip link set tun0 up
ip -6 route add default via tun0
```

Running

```
ping6 google.com
```

does not work.

Definitely, the NAT in the modem is complicating the thing as always NAT does.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Lol a bot that pretend to understand how GRE tunnels and networking work. Bot is Friday go to drink a beer

Comment: I have found a similar discussion here https://serverfault.com/questions/926948/linux-gre-tunnel-remote-address-parameter but the solution is tailored for a Linux router that does NAT. In my case my ISP modem in front having static IP has only port forwarding and other basics functionality of a modem.